# Why did Shiraz try to kill Refaat

Tags: plot-explanation, paranormal

In the first episode of *[Paranormal](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt12411074/)* there is a scene where Shiraz asks Refaat to jump off the roof

[image]

> However in the last episode it is revealed that Shiraz is actually always protecting Refaat, which is shows from previous episodes. If that is the case, why did she try to kill him in the 1st episode.

> [image]

Comment: Do we really need spoiler tags on a show that aired nearly two years ago?